# How to align svg with header navigation in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, svg

so I'm experimenting with SVG for my logo and I'm not sure how to pull off what I am trying to do. I've done the logo in inkscape and I'm struggling to get the logo text aligned with the other elements in my header. Ideally, I would like the text to have the same font size as the nav elements.
You can see my test site here: http://138.197.1.44:8080. I have played with the SVG's inline width, where I can get the logo the right size but not aligned. What I've read about svg production and alignment is kind of confusing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve].  Links to external sites are discouraged here, because they could be temporary, or get fixed. And then this question and any answers you get will likely become useless to future readers.

Comment: Hi @Paul, the link contained in the post has the svg and mark up, please let me know what else to add?

Comment: First preference would be a [Stack Overflow code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).  Otherwise a jsfiddle, codepen, etc would be acceptable.